# sql reporting services unhandled error with subreport in 3rd level group

Tags: sql, service, reporting, subreport

I'm getting an error when trying to put a subreport inside a inside a 3rd level group of a table or list (it doesn't matter, same error)

I have put a clean subreport without datasource without parameters, just a textbox
when I put that subreport inside 1st or 2nd level group it's ok, when I put it inside a 3rd level group(or higher) I receive an unhandled error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, my solution is not to put suberports in 3rd level group, that's it for now
you could put the 3rd level, 4th level ... etc group in the subreport or somthing like that i guess, that's what i did